# Using a Console-only NetBSD VM

Tags: libvirt, netbsd

I am experimenting with NetBSD and seeing if I can get the Fenrir screenreader to run on it. However, I hit a snag post install; the console that I was using for the installation was working perfectly fine, however it stopped working alltogether once I completed the install. For reference, here is the line I used for virt-install:

```
virt-install --connect qemu:///system -n netbsd-testing \
             --ram 4096 --vcpus=8 \
             --cpu=host \
             -c /home/sektor/Downloads/boot-com.iso  \
             --os-type=netbsd --os-variant=netbsd8.0 \
             --disk=pool=devel,size=100,format=qcow2 \
             -w network=default --nographics
```

When it asked me for the type of terminal I was using (this being the NetBSD install program), I accepted the default which was VT200. As I recall, I told it to use the BIOS for booting, and not any of the comm serial ports. Has anyone had any further experience with using no graphics on a Libvirt virtualized machine, and have any points as to how to get a working console?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add `--serial pty` to virt-install?  Or add the following XML to your VM configuration by virsh edit?

```
<console type='pty'>
  <target type='serial' port='0'/>
</console>
```

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion; it worked a charm.

Comment: Good to hear :)